# How to sent arp packets to queue from arptables 

Tags: linux, iptables, packets, arp

My aim was to find a way to process(drop,accept,forward and etc.) packets that are from Layer 2 ...

I know that "iptables" in *inux allow us to send packet to "NFQUEUE" for further packet processing ....

but it support layer 3 packets ... which means it does not detect packets that are from Layer 2..

although "arptables" detect packets that are destine for Layer 2, I couldn't find a way to send it to "NFQUEUE"

is there any way that can let us choose whether or not we should accept/drop/continue the layer packets?

Comment: Layer 2? maybe you want `ebtables`, not `arptables`?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Did you find a way to connect to this queue (libnetfilter didnt work for me)

Answer (score 0):

Only ebtables has a target (-j arpreply) to generate ARP packets as of this date, though you can filter with either ebtables and arptables. NFQUEUE is also usable from ebtables, and in fact, can be quickly extended for arptables by just adding an entry to it, but so far, arptables has been pretty much a nice program, even more so than ebtables.

Comment: I tried using ebtables ... it does not allow me to "queue" my packets like what "iptables" do ...

Comment: So Jorgensen write it's possible to use the NFQUEUE in ebtables too! But how it works? I have to change the source code or not? Perhaps you can pm me? Or anybody else?